# Adding multiple subjects/grades in moderncv and cventry

Tags: moderncv

Is it possible to add multiple subjects and grades using the `moderncv` class like shown below?
[image: Image showing multiple subjects and grades under the college name, with the city and dates on the far right]

All I have so far is the code below

```
\cventry{Date--Date}{Subject}{College Name}{City}     
{\textit{Grade}}{}
```

I've tried searching on Google for the answer using 'multiple subjects moderncv' and its variations, and I have looked on Google images to see if there was any images of something similar. The only code I've tried has been:

```
\cventry{Date--Date}{Subject\newline Subject 2}{College Name}{City}     
{\textit{Grade}\newline\textit{Grade 2}}{}
```

Which failed to create either `\newline`

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xl}
\textbf{College Name} & \textbf{City} \\
Subject 1--Grade & year--year \\
Subject 2--Grade & year--year \\
Subject 3--Grade & year--year \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To align thetabular  material with the section title, you can use an appropriate space:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\hspace*{\dimexpr\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth\relax}\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\hintscolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth\relax}{Xl}
\textbf{College Name} & \textbf{City} \\
Subject 1--Grade & year--year \\
Subject 2--Grade & year--year \\
Subject 3--Grade & year--year \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option would be to use `\cventry` and `\cvitem`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\cventry{}{College Name}{}{}{\hfill\textbf{City}}{}
\cvitem{}{Subject 1--Grade\hfill year--year}
\cvitem{}{Subject 2--Grade\hfill year--year}
\cvitem{}{Subject 3--Grade\hfill year--year}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes, I know, but the question doesn't specify what's considered "good alignment" with respect to other elements. In any case, I'll add some remark about this. Thanks.